# Encrypt querystring using HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, encryption

How to encrypt querystring using HttpHandler?

Comment: Can you describe more in detail what you want to achieve (such as why you want to encrypt the query string and similar)? That will probably give you better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article that might help

http://madskristensen.net/post/HttpModule-for-query-string-encryption.aspx